# How to stay dry in the nether regions?

Tags: hiking

I'm outdoors quite a bit. But the one thing that takes me out of action is sweat buildup and rubbing in my nether regions. It can literally take me out of action for a few days. I think it comes down to friction and sweat. I use performance boxers daily but it doesn't seem to help the situation. It does seem like hiking causes the majority of these problems.

Answer (score 3):

That kind of problem is miserable, but fairly common. There are a few things I'd suggest to solve it.

- **Good, wicking underwear**. It sounds like you've tried at least one
        version, but it is worth experimenting with different styles, brands and
        materials. I'm a fan of merino wool for dealing with sweat. I find
        it works as well as or better than any synthetic performance fabrics
        I've tried. Silk is another natural fabric that might help with
        chafing.
- **Anti-chafe cream**. Body Glide is the brand I'm familiar with, but
        there are many others. It acts as a slick layer on your skin to
        reduce rubbing.
- **Weight loss**. Obviously, this isn't available to people who are
        already thin, but if extra fat is causing or exacerbating the
        rubbing, weight loss will help. A much longer term solution than the
        other two.

Answer (score 0):

good ideas Karen.
others:

- hike in shorts even if it is cold.  Thin nylon pants instead of heavy cotton jeans.  Consider a Utili-Kilt which are completely open and ventilated.  Your legs generate a lot of muscle heat while hiking and really don't need much insulation
- compression shorts as a concept are all about holding in place and preventing movement.  Like Bras- "Lift and Separate"
- (thin) running tights, providing both the support and less insulation ideas
- very thin wicking speedo-type briefs for support of the boys, PLUS very thin compression shorts over it (not too small, not too compressive) or boxer-brief type underwear -- not for heat retention but to provide a "sacrificial" rubbing layer of fabric -- similar to why people hike with two pairs of socks, one a thin liner sock.  With this, definitely shorts or kilt to ventilate and keep cool